# mount an encrypted zfs partition

Tags: mount, hard-drive, encryption, zfs

So I have to mount an encrypted zfs partition to fix my computer. I have looked everywhere but I can't mount it with the info I found. Every time I do `sudo zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/k/ rpool` it does not fail but I can't get to the files. If I mount it in disks I get `error mounting /dev/sda4 to /media/ubuntu/rpool2: unknown filesystem type zfs_member (udisk-error-quark, 0)`. Most likely the partition is not mounting because it is encrypted. How do I mount it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mount a ZFS pool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123126/how-do-i-mount-a-zfs-pool)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below example workflow to perform the following:

1. Install ZFS and verify the installation
2. Locate and import a ZFS pool from a disk partition
3. Set the mountpoint of the desired ZFS pool and/or dataset
4. Decrypt they ZFS pool keystore
5. Mount the cipher key and load it into ZFS
6. Mount your ZFS pool and/or dataset to the desired point

```bash
ZFS_DISK='/dev/sdX'
ZFS_POOL_PARTITION='/dev/sdXn'
ZFS_POOL='rpool'
ZFS_POOL_DATASET='DATA'  # 'ROOT' or 'USERDATA' for Ubuntu
MOUNTPOINT='/mnt'

# install zfs (using apt-get, yum, dnf, pacman, etc)
sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux
sudo zfs --version

# locate zfs disk and pool
sudo lsblk -af "$ZFS_DISK"
sudo fdisk -l "$ZFS_DISK"
 
# create mountpoint directories for zfs pool and cipher key
sudo mkdir -p "$MOUNTPOINT"
sudo mkdir -p /zfskey
 
# import pool from partition
sudo zpool import -d "$ZFS_POOL_PARTITION" "$ZFS_POOL"
sudo zpool list
sudo zpool status -P "$ZFS_POOL"

# get and set the mountpoint for our zfs pool/dataset
# NOTE: mountpoints may collide with current filesystem,
# as mountpoints inherit from higher-level mountpoints
sudo zfs get mounted "$ZFS_POOL" -t filesystem -r
sudo zfs get mountpoint "$ZFS_POOL" -t filesystem -r
sudo zfs get mountpoint "$ZFS_POOL/$ZFS_POOL_DATASET"  # BACKUP THIS VALUE
sudo zfs set mountpoint="$MOUNTPOINT" "$ZFS_POOL/$ZFS_POOL_DATASET"
 
# decrypt zfs keystore and load cipher key
sudo cryptsetup open "/dev/zvol/$ZFS_POOL/keystore" zfskey  # creates /dev/dm-0 dm-1 dm-2
ls -l /dev/mapper/zfskey  # /dev/mapper/zfskey -> /dev/dm-n
sudo cryptsetup -v status zfskey
sudo mount /dev/mapper/zfskey /zfskey
df -H
ls -l /zfskey
sudo cat /zfskey/system.key | sudo zfs load-key -L prompt "$ZFS_POOL"

# mount the decrypted pool and/or dataset
sudo zfs mount "$ZFS_POOL/$ZFS_POOL_DATASET"
sudo zfs list
ls -la "$MOUNTPOINT"
```

Your directory should now be mounted and visible.

Comment: Most comprehensive answer I found on mounting a ZFS filesystem, saved my day. Needs to get higher ratings so people can see this before going to the others.