# Mounting encrypted rpool using Ubuntu Live CD, successful but broken links, out of ideas

Tags: mount, encryption, live-cd, zfs

VM took a crash during operation and now won't boot.  Would like to rip the data out of the encrypted home directory and then start from scratch. I boot the VM with Ubuntu Live CD, below are the steps i took from various readings here and on the web. I get the system.key loaded, but it seems the loaded key doesn't decrypt the rpool directories when i go to import.  After importing, I get two broken link files in the live cd /mnt directory. Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop (Has red X, purple arrow and orange lock on the icon) and readme.txt (same three icons on it) Both target location is /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop. The folder /ecryptfs-utils doesn't exist on the live cd, hence the broken link.  I know I'm missing a step, just not sure where or what it is.  I've looked for days.  I also made a test VM with the same setup using the same zfs encryption.  I get the same scenario with the mounted/imported broken links when booting from live cd. (My thought was maybe the data location is just broken on my original broken VM, but having the same result happen on the working test VM, tells me i'm missing something somewhere.    Thank you.

> *Sudo Zpool import (**shows my rpool and bpool**)*

> *Sudo zpool import -Ff "ID of rpool"* (**imports the rpool**)

> *Sudo zpool scrub rpool*

> *sudo cat /media/ubuntu/keystore-rpool/system.key | sudo zfs load-key -L prompt rpool* (**asks for passphase, type in, new mount shows up unlocked with system.key with red x on it**.)

> *sudo zfs set canmount=on rpool* (**had to use this command because it said canmount was off**)

> *sudo zfs load-key -L /path/to/keyfile/rpool  (**maybe redundent, i'm not sure**)

> *sudo zfs mount -a

I've followed these guides to no avail

[Mount an ecrypted ubuntu zfs file system from ubuntu live cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332447/how-to-mount-an-encrypted-ubuntu-20-10-zfs-file-system-from-an-ubuntu-live-cd)

[import encrypted pool if you don't where the key must be mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730921/zfs-on-linux-how-to-import-an-encrypted-pool-if-you-dont-know-where-key-must-b)