# Chroot into an encrypted ZFS installation from live media or alternatives

Tags: partitioning, encryption, zfs, chroot

For some reason, usb-guard decided to remove all of the rules I have written that allowed my keyboard and mouse. I've had this happen before from myself messing up the configuration, but this setup has been running without modification for months.

Anyways, the usual fix for this is to load up a kali live disk, decrypt the luks partition, and chroot into the machine to edit the configuration.

I don't know how to do this with Ubuntu 22.04 and encrypted ZFS.

If it's not possible in a similar way that I described, I'm looking for alternatives as well.

SSH is disabled, so that's not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: "*Anyways, the usual fix for this is to load up a kali live disk, decrypt the luks partition, and chroot into the machine to edit the configuration.*" ... It's the same process, but you don't need other distributions, you can use an Ubuntu live CD ... You don't even need to `chroot` to modify some file, just mount the partition decrypting if encrypted and you will have access to your files.

Comment: @Raffa I messed around and googled a bunch of stuff. Using the ubuntu live cd, I can't get the zfs partition to mount because it expects a raw key and not a passphrase.

Comment: Have you come across this post: https://askubuntu.com/q/1332447